# What file in the Windows boot Manager loads the disk driver to then load windows on the c:\

Tags: windows, boot, drivers, windows-server-2012

we had a Nutanix Windows VM boot directly into the recovery partition as it could not see its system partition.

After a quick google which came up with this [troubleshooting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems) guide, I can see that I should be looking in the boot partition.

I was able to boot from a Windows DVD ISO and reload the specific VirtIO SCSI driver, however I wish to understand where this configuration is kept in Windows.

I'm guessing it is in **\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootgfw.efi** but would like confirmation or otherwise from anyone who might know as to where its config lives - maybe from there I can figure out why it was dropped/lost to begin with.

Many thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002542/how-does-uefi-boot-mode-boot-flows for or https://news.saferbytes.it/analisi/2013/10/windows-uefi-startup-a-technical-overview/ for explanation of the boot process.

Comment: thanks, these are good!